# How to cast one interface to another in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am stuck with the following problem:

I have a class, which was generated from an xsd file using the Delphi 7 XML Data binding wizard (New -> Other -> XML Databindng).

I need to find a way to add methods to the generated code:

```
IXMLGlobeSettingsType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{9A8F5C55-F593-4C70-85D2-68FB97ABA467}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_General: IXMLGeneralSettingsType;
    function Get_Projector: IXMLProjectorSettingsType;
    function Get_LineMode: IXMLLineDrawingSettingsType;

    { Methods & Properties }
    property General: IXMLGeneralSettingsType read Get_General;
    property Projector: IXMLProjectorSettingsType read Get_Projector;
    property LineMode: IXMLLineDrawingSettingsType read Get_LineMode;

    //procedure SetDefault;   {To be added}
  end;
```

The interface is implemented by a corresponding class, which is also generated by the wizard:

```
TXMLGlobeSettingsType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLGlobeSettingsType)
  protected
    { IXMLGlobeSettingsType }
    function Get_General: IXMLGeneralSettingsType;
    function Get_Projector: IXMLProjectorSettingsType;
    function Get_LineMode: IXMLLineDrawingSettingsType;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;
```

And in order to define my own extensions to the generated code, I have defined the following interface:

```
IDefaultable = interface
   procedure SetDefault;
end;
```

With the following implementation class:

```
DefaultableXMLGlobeSettingsType = class(TXMLGlobeSettingsType, IDefaultable)
  public
    procedure SetDefault;
  end;
```

However, I just realized that Delphi 7 does not let me cast one interface to another (or even from an interface to an object). So the following code will raise an error:

```
defaultSettings : IDefaultable;    
FGlobeSettingsIntf: IXMLGlobeSettingsType; // FGlobeSettingsIntf is in fact a DefaultableXMLGlobeSettingsType

// some code

defaultSettings := FGlobeSettingsIntf as IDefaultable; // error: operator not applicable to this operand type
```

I am pretty much stuck here. How can get around this error? Is there a way (even an ugly one) in Delphi 7 to cast the Interface to an object and then back to another interface.

Comment: OK accepted yours (sorry Uwe!).

Comment: Never mind! David is correct - there is nothing to argue about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
defaultSettings := FGlobeSettingsIntf as IDefaultable;
// error: operator not applicable to this operand type
```

This error indicates that the definition of `IDefaultable` does not include a GUID. Without a GUID it is not possible to query for an interface, which is what the `as` operator does in this context.

The `as` operator, when used with a interface on the right hand side, is implemented by a call to `IInterface.QueryInterface`. That requires a GUID to be associated with the interface.

Resolve the problem by adding a GUID when you declare `IDefaultable`.

Comment: Tip: use Ctrl+Shift+G in the editor to compute and insert a new unique GUID below the interface type first line.

Comment: @David Heffernan Accepting your answer for the sake of completeness. Uwe's answer is also quite useful. Thanks Uwe!

Comment: Actually, one can implement QueryInterface to return any interface that can somehow be associated with a GUID. The custom QueryInterface could associate an interface with a GUID in other ways than the built-in one. The usual (and built-in) way is what you describe, but it could work quite differently, and then a GUID doesn't have to be defined for the interface in the way it is usually done in Delphi. I don't know *why* anyone would do it differently, though, but that was not my point. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Sticking to the question at hand, `as` will lead to a call to QI passing the GUID associated with the interface. So, actually, the only way to resolve the error, without changing the code that uses `as`, is to add a GUID to the interface.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `Supports` is for:

```
if Supports(FGlobeSettingsIntf, IDefaultable, defaultSettings) then begin
  defaultSettings.SetDefault;
end;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Accepting it because it seems to be the clean way to cast from interface to another, although the main reason my code was not compiling was due to a missing GUID (see edit of the original question). However the signature of supports is not clear to me: `function Supports(const Instance: IInterface; const IID: TGUID; out Intf): Boolean;`   the second parameter is `TGUID`. In my case it is `IDefaultable`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BigONotation an interface type can be passed to a TGUID and the compiler will substitute the interface's actual guid

Comment: @RemyLebeau Many thanks for the clarifications! That stats to make sense.